# replacing an object in an array based on a key an setting it in the state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a react state variable

```
const [boxes,SetBoxes]=useState([]);
```

after performing an operation i have  the boxes array as

```
boxes=[
    {
        "code": "756WP",
        "id": "full",
        "name": "Full Cart",
        "boxId": "box6",
        "cartQuantityAllots": [
            {
                "code": "5",
                "cartType": "halfCart",
                "typesOfItems": [
                    {
                        "key": "02f2c8e0-cd40-11ed-8563-092a964acecc",
                        "name": "Bar Cart - Beer & Wine",
                        "value": "Bar Cart - Beer & Wine",
                        "label": "Bar Cart - Beer & Wine"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],
        "index": "Galley1",
        "imageGalley": "/static/media/galley4.961c9560760d59cd336f.png"
    }
]
```

another array is to be added to the array boxes using state which is

```
const obj=

    [{
        "code": "756WP",
        "id": "full",
        "name": "Full Cart",
        "boxId": "box6",
        "cartQuantityAllots": [
            {
                "code": "5",
                "cartType": "halfCart",
                "typesOfItems": [
                    {
                        "key": "02f2c8e0-cd40-11ed-8563-092a964acecc",
                        "name": "Bar Cart - Beer & Wine",
                        "value": "Bar Cart - Beer & Wine",
                        "label": "Bar Cart - Beer & Wine"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "code": "4",
                "cartType": "halfCart",
                "typesOfItems": [
                    {
                        "key": "02f2c8e0-cd40-11ed-8563-092a964acecc",
                        "name": "Amenities Pouch",
                        "value": "Amenities Pouch",
                        "label": "Amenities Pouch"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],
        "index": "Galley1",
        "imageGalley": "/static/media/galley4.961c9560760d59cd336f.png"
    }]
```

since the boxId key in boxes array is same as boxId in the obj array

i did

```
const i = boxes.findIndex(x => x.boxId === 'box6')

      boxes[i] = [ ...obj]
setBoxes([...boxes,...obj])
```

but i end up getting two objects instead of one
in boxes array as

```
 const boxes=  [
        {
            "code": "756WP",
            "id": "full",
            "name": "Full Cart",
            "boxId": "box6",
            "cartQuantityAllots": [
                {
                    "code": "5",
                    "cartType": "halfCart",
                    "typesOfItems": [
                        {
                            "key": "02f2c8e0-cd40-11ed-8563-092a964acecc",
                            "name": "Bar Cart - Beer & Wine",
                            "value": "Bar Cart - Beer & Wine",
                            "label": "Bar Cart - Beer & Wine"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "index": "Galley1",
            "imageGalley": "/static/media/galley4.961c9560760d59cd336f.png"
        },
        {
            "code": "756WP",
            "id": "full",
            "name": "Full Cart",
            "boxId": "box6",
            "cartQuantityAllots": [
                {
                    "code": "5",
                    "cartType": "halfCart",
                    "typesOfItems": [
                        {
                            "key": "02f2c8e0-cd40-11ed-8563-092a964acecc",
                            "name": "Bar Cart - Beer & Wine",
                            "value": "Bar Cart - Beer & Wine",
                            "label": "Bar Cart - Beer & Wine"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "code": "4",
                    "cartType": "halfCart",
                    "typesOfItems": [
                        {
                            "key": "02f2c8e0-cd40-11ed-8563-092a964acecc",
                            "name": "Amenities Pouch",
                            "value": "Amenities Pouch",
                            "label": "Amenities Pouch"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "index": "Galley1",
            "imageGalley": "/static/media/galley4.961c9560760d59cd336f.png"
        }
    ]
```

i clearly need the second object in the array and the first should not be there since the boxId is same as of the second object.is there an easier approach for this?

Comment: *i clearly need the second object in the array* on what basis? Do you just want to replace an object if object with `boxId` is already present or you want to add `cartQuantityAllots` in the existing object?

Comment: Don't `setBoxes` then. Just `boxes[i] = obj[0]` should be enough.

Comment: what you said is right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are adding a new box to the boxes array, but you need to update the inner array.

So state update logic can be something like this:

```
    const obj = {
      code: "4",
      cartType: "halfCart",
      typesOfItems: [
        {
          key: "02f2c8e0-cd40-11ed-8563-092a964acecc",
          name: "Amenities Pouch",
          value: "Amenities Pouch",
          label: "Amenities Pouch"
        }
      ]
    };

    SetBoxes((boxes) =>
      boxes.map((b) =>
        b.boxId === "box6"
          ? { ...b, cartQuantityAllots: [...b.cartQuantityAllots, obj] }
          : b
      )
    );
```